# Data structure design with O(log n) amortized time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm working on this problem but I'm pretty confused on how to solve it:

Design a data structure that supports the following operations in amortized O(log n) time, where n is the total number of elements:

1. Ins(k): Insert a new element with key k
2. Extract-Max: Find and remove the element with largest key
3. Extract-Min: Find and remove the element with smallest key
4. Union: Merge two different sets of elements

How do I calculate the amortized time? Isn't this already something like a hash table? Or is it a variant of it?
I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.
Thank you!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue

Answer (score 2):

What you're proposing isn't something that most hash tables are equipped to deal with because hash tables don't usually support finding the min and max elements quickly while supporting deletions.

However, this *is* something that you could do with a pair of priority queues that support melding. For example, suppose that you back your data structure with [two binomial heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) - a min-heap and a max-heap. Every time you insert an element into your data structure, you add it to both the min-heap and the max-heap. However, you slightly modify the two heaps so that each element in the heap stores a pointer to its corresponding element in the other heap; that way, given a node in the min-heap, you can find the corresponding node in the max-heap and vice-versa.

Now, to do an extract-min or extract-max, you just apply a find-min operation to the min-heap or a find-max operation to the max-heap to get the result. Then, delete that element from both heaps using the normal binomial heap delete operation. (You can use the pointer you set up during the insert step to quickly locate the sibling element in the other heap).

Finally, for a union operation, just apply the normal binomial heap merge operation to the corresponding min-heaps and max-heaps.

Since all of the described operations requires O(1) operations on binomial heaps, each of them runs in time O(log n) worst-case, with no amortization needed.

Generally speaking, the data structure you're describing is called a [double-ended priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue). There are a couple of specialized data structures you can use to meet those requirements, though the one described above is probably the easiest to build with off-the-shelf components.

Comment: How would you merge the queues in less than O(n) time?

Comment: @craig6553: from the linked wikipedia article on binomial heaps - "Because of its unique structure, a binomial tree of order k can be constructed from two trees of order k−1 trivially by attaching one of them as the leftmost child of the root of the other tree. This feature is central to the merge operation of a binomial heap, which is its major advantage over other conventional heaps.", when they're equal size it's trivial. When unequal, it's a little more complex, but not too much.

Comment: @craig65535 Binomial heaps can be merged in time O(log n). Each heap consists of a set of O(log n) different trees, and there's an algorithm that merges those trees together in time O(log n) that's similar to how binary addition works. If you haven't seen binomial heaps before, check out [these lecture slides](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/06/Slides06.pdf), which gives a good motivation for them.